# How can I use a custom prefix for international calls?

Tags: calls, international-prefix

In my country, we have to use a prefix before dialing an international number, depending on which provider we use. For example, I use an international calling company for which I have to dial 019 before dialing the international number.

Now, having to edit each and every international phone number in my address book to add a 109 would be annoying. And when I move providers, having to do the whole process again would be very annoying.

Is there a way to tell Android, "every time you see a +, just dial 019 instead"? Or any other solution?

(I use Cyanogenmod.)

Comment: The world would be a better place if every carrier/phone provider would just recognize the [canonical number format E.123](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.123). Shame on your provider ;)

Comment: be easier to just insert/add a new contact with international dialling code prefix with their number; that's what I do, so if I was to go abroad, I can dial the contact as the number is there already!

Comment: @t0mm13b: that would require me to edit each and every contact, and duplicate each phone number to have both `+` and `019` (or whatever the international dialing prefix is).  I don't think your suggestion saves any effort at all.

Answer (score 1):

The only apps I have found to be able to do this kind of editing are SIP dialers like [CSipSimple](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csipsimple) and [SipDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sipdroid.sipua). They integrate into the regular call setup and can run a set of rewrite rules and filters to decide where and how to place the call.

I believe both can do this even for regular (cell) calls, and even when no SIP provider has been configured.

Answer (score 1):

Nightmare. I can't believe an Android phone would ship with such a bug.  Bought phone at Best Buy, traveled to Europe, bought a local SIM card. All my Google contacts have + (country code) in front of them. I can dial numbers direct, but without the Plus Sign (+). I can't dial anything in my address book. Researched it and painfully so, I found a third party app (prefixer) that does the trick after trying a few. You basically want to add "00" in front of the +.

It's simple enough, but I don't care for the fact that it's not native to the phone. Here is the configuration below - best of luck

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution. Could you add a link to the app you're recommending?